# Debug ios Problems in command line- Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, debugging, xcodebuild

I built a project to iPhone and debugging it in Xcode 4.3.2 works fine. However, I want to debug it in command line, so I run:

```
xcodebuild -target NAMEOFTARGET -sdk SDKPATH -configuration Release
```

it should be the same as in Xcode, but I'm getting some errors and it does not compile! Maybe someone could help...

```
-Prefix-cfqwmqlvdeltqcceqguoaugscmoq/Igor2305-Prefix.pch.d
error: can't exec '/opt/local/bin/gcc-apple-4.2' (No such file or directory)
Command /opt/local/bin/gcc-apple-4.2 failed with exit code 71
 ** BUILD FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
ProcessPCH /var/folders/d7/sx0vvl0537l4x7md9b35m7br0000gn/C/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/Igor2305-Prefix-fwljjtsqayhghvfeivuxdyjuvt/Igor2305-Prefix.pch.pth Igor2305/Igor2305-Prefix.pch normal armv6 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
ProcessPCH /var/folders/d7/sx0vvl057l4x7md9b35m7br00gn/C/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/Igor2305-Prefi-cfqwmqlvdeltqceqguoaugscmoq/Igor2305-Prefix.pch.pth Igor2305/Igor2305-Prefix.pch normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's looking for GCC in `/opt/` and not finding it.  That's not a standard installation location for the GCC bundled with Xcode.  The following command will tell you where Xcode is looking for its developer tools:

```
xcode-select -print-path
```

To change it, run:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

That path is for the standard Xcode installation location as installed through the App Store.  If you've installed it elsewhere, you'll have to alter the path accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for answer, You mean xcodebuild - select....(bot working) i cant use the X code.app to transfer parameters

Comment: No, I don't mean `xcodebuild -select`, I mean exactly what I typed.

Comment: I cant find it, in my /bin folder i have only xcodebuil,xcrun,no xcode there.

Comment: I never said Xcode was in `/bin/`, I don't understand why you are looking there for it.  You need to run `xcode-select`.  Not `xcodebuild -select`.  Not `xcode -select`.  Have you tried copying and pasting the first command I suggested?  What does it tell you?

Comment: Now it's worked(tried xcode -select).. but i steal getting the same errors with /opt.

Comment: What have you actually done?  The first command simply prints diagnostic information.  It doesn't change any settings, so by itself it wouldn't have fixed anything.  That's what the second command is for.  Did you run `xcode-select` or `xcode -select`?  The two are different.  What did it tell you?

Comment: Yes, i understand it! I run the xcode-select. The xcode-select -print-path showed the old path, it was i think /Developer, i fix it with the second command, and now when i check this path it's shows the correct one: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer. But the problem is steal the same....

Comment: What environment variables do you have present in your shell?

Comment: TMPDIR=/var/folders/d7/sx0vvl05b35m7br0000gn/T/*
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/tmp/launch-53cDUX/Render*
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=303*
OLDPWD=/Users/igor*
TERM_SESSION_ID=BC243-B725-A6-92F761*
LC_ALL=es_ES.UTF-8*
USER=igor*
COMMAND_MODE=unix2003*
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/launch-kM5r/Listeners*
Apple_Ubiquity_Message=/tmp/launch-dGDWse/Apple_Ubiquity_Message*
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0:0*
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/local/bin
PWD=/Users/igor/.hudson/jobs/Build
HOME=/Users/igor
SHLVL=1
LOGNAME=igor
CC=/opt/local/bin/gcc-apple-4.2

Comment: That last one is your problem.  Unset the `CC` environment variable.

Comment: WOW thank's its passed it... but now new error: The following build commands failed:
 CpResource www build/Release-iphoneos/Igor2305.app/www
(1 failure)